# how to select distinct values from 2 tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

table1

```
id 
1 
2 
3 
4  
5
```

table2

```
id 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8
```

I want to result in this way:

```
id  
1
2
3
6
7
8
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Have you tried at least get all number from both tables? Then, suddenly, there is a key word "DISTINCT" defined in sql. Try the first query, improve your question

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it in MySQL, using `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
union all
select t2.id
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eed3b6f6c2e16abcaf1afa9d9226e4a7)**:

```
| id |
| -: |
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
```

Comment: I think the `ALL` is superfluous, since the where clauses already excludes duplicates (I didn't DV you, eh :p)

Comment: @Cid . . . `UNION ALL` is always preferred over `UNION` because it does not incur overhead to remove dupicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you, I guess I've mistaken `UNION ALL` and `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query like following.

```
select coalesce(id1, id2) as id
from (
    select t1.id as id1
        ,t2.id as id2
    from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id

    union

    select t1.id as id1
        ,t2.id as id2
    from table1 t1
    right join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    ) T
where t.id1 is null
    or t.id2 is null
```

Comment: I suspect a 'full join' is requred.

Comment: thanks @P.Salmon, i misunderstood the question initially.

Answer (score 0):

This might run faster than the solution by GMB.

```
select table1.id
from table1 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where table2.id IS NULL
union all
select table2.id
from table2 left join table1 on table1.id = table2.id
where table1.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

> DISTINCT

your example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id from  table1 a, table2 b where a.id =b.id
```

Comment: Have you read question carefully and  tested this query? It returns 4,5 but OP expects  1 2 3 6 7 8

Comment: Please note that this way to write joins is not the standard anymore since about 28 years (1992)

Answer (score -1):

try the following

```sql
select distinct id from (
    select id from table 1
    union 
    select id from table 2
)
```

Comment: could you provide some explanation on why this is given as a solution

Comment: This is not going to filter out the values which are in both tables.